# Python 3: Add string to OBJECTS within a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, indexing

I am sure it is a very trivial question but I can not seem to find anything online, perhaps because I am not using the right terminology..

I have a list that looks like so:

```
list = ["abc",
        "ded"]
```

I know how to append elements to this list, how to add elements to the beginning, etc. 
What I need to do is to add a string (more specifically an asterisk (*)) before and after each object in this list. So it should look like:

```
list = ["*abc*",
        "*ded*"]
```

I have tried:

```
asterisk = '*'
list = [asterisk] + list[0]
list = asterisk + List[0]
list = ['*'] + list[0]
list = * + list[0]

asterisk = list(asterisk)
list = [asterisk] + list[0]
```

and I always get:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Then of course there is the problem with adding it before and after each of the objects in the list.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're thinking too hard about the list when all you have to do is iterate over it and act on each item. A list comprehension is perfect for that as some answers already said.

Answer (score 1):

Just string interpolate it in as follows:

```
[f'*{s}*' for s in ["abc","ded"]]
```

Output

```
['*abc*', '*ded*']
```

Note this is for Python 3.6+ only.

Comment: In Python 3.5-, `['*{}*'.format(s) for s in ["abc","ded"]]`

Answer (score 1):

For your list you use this beautiful syntax, called "list comprehension":

```
lst = ['abc', 'ded']
lst = ['*'+s+'*' for s in lst]
print(lst)
```

This would get you:

```
['*abc*', '*ded*']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a list comprehension to adjust

```
[('*'+i) for i in asterix]
```

you can give it a name just for good measure so that you can call it later

Comment: "add an asterisk (*) before **and after** each object in this list". And the parenthesis are unnecessary

Comment: the parenthesis are just to make it a little more obvious on how it should work i know they are not needed @Pynchia

Answer (score 0):

You can join the asterisks with each word

```
asterisked = [w.join('**') for w in lst]
```

The trick here is to remember that strings are iterables, so you can pass a string that contains two asterisks to the word's join method to let it prepend the word with the first asterisk and append the second one

Comment: This works and it's interesting, but I wouldn't recommend it to a newbie since it's not obvious how it works and it's not very flexible

Comment: I understand your concern and I am sure the OP can pick what he/she prefers/understands now. SO is here to provide help and several solutions, to the OP and to others